# Java regex not matching, regex looks OK

Tags: java, regex

The following returns no matches:

```
String patternStr = "((19\\d{2}|20\\d{2})-([0-2]\\d{2}|3[0-5]\\d)-(([0-1]\\d|2[0-3])[0-5]\\d[0-5]\\d))";
String fullPath = aFile.getAbsolutePath(); 
// fullPath should expand to this: "/home/user1/2013-023-135159_abcd_001/File.txt"

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher m = p.matcher(fullPath);
if (m.matches())
{
   System.out.println("Matches found");
}
```

It should match the date portion, 2013-023-135159. I tested it online and the regex looks OK.

Comment: Yeah, I have them escaped, I just copied the regex from the online tester

Comment: But `matches()` compares the regular expression against the entire string - it doesn't look for matching portions within the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use:

```
m.find()
```

instead of:

```
m.matches()
```

As your regex is matching the parts of the input string not fully as expected by `m.matches()`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pR4hT8/1)

Comment: I thought matches does match all occurrences at once. Thanks.